# Emscripten: Map CWD into process

Tags: emscripten

I am working on a tiny tool that would be nice to have in JavaScript land as well - in fact, that tool is used to bootstrap it's native self.

But in order to do so, it needs to read files from disk. And as it is known, only `NODEFS` actually has that feature. But I just can't figure out how to use `FS.mount` in order to just map the whole CWD in a way that `fopen("./foo.txt","r")` would "just work".

The tool is only intended to run on Node, therefore I can be certain that I have `NODEFS` available to me at all time.

How do I perform this mapping? Thanks!

Comment: Does this not help: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tests/fs/test_nodefs_rw.c

Comment: Ouch. I clearly oversaw that one when I was browsing the source tree... Yeah, i mounted the cwd in `/CWD` and changed to that, and it works perfectly. Oops...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MarginBroadhurst, I could just mount the CWD in a sub-folder of root and navigate to that - and problem is solved.